# how to generate a script for the entire database

Tags: sql, t-sql, azure-sql-database, ssms

I've attempted to [generate scripts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/scripting/generate-scripts-sql-server-management-studio?view=sql-server-ver15). I've used both of these options:

[image]

When attempting to execute the generated script, it works on the initial database creation.

All subsequent attempts to run the generated script result in the following error:

```
Msg 1781, Level 16, State 1, Line 8739
Column already has a DEFAULT bound to it.
Msg 1750, Level 16, State 0, Line 8739
Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.
```

[image]

This code seems to work on initial database creation but not on subsequent exections:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[cfg].[DF__LookupCol__IsPri__46DD686B]') AND type = 'D')
BEGIN
ALTER TABLE [cfg].[LookupColumns] ADD  DEFAULT (CONVERT([bit],(0))) FOR [IsPrimaryKey]
END
GO
```

I've attempted it this as well with the same result:

```
ALTER TABLE [cfg].[LookupColumns] ADD CONSTRAINT LookupColumnsIsPrimaryKeyConstraint DEFAULT (CONVERT([bit],(0))) FOR [IsPrimaryKey]
```

**What am I doing wrong? What is the meaning of this error? *Column already has a DEFAULT bound to it***?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is indeed because you didn't name your constraints, so the second time it attempts to drop the *old* name then add an additional constraint.

The first time you run the script it checks for a default constraint called `DF__LookupCol__IsPri__46DD686B`, which of course does not exist.

Then it runs

`ALTER TABLE [cfg].[LookupColumns] ADD  DEFAULT (CONVERT([bit],(0))) FOR [IsPrimaryKey]`

Which creates a new constraint with a *new* auto-generated name.  Next time you run the script, it tries to drop `DF__LookupCol__IsPri__46DD686B` again, which still doesn't exist, and then tries to add a new constraint, which fails.

So to be able to re-run this script, you should name all your constraints and indexes *before* generating the scripts.

You can find the system-named default constraints like this:

```
select name, object_name(object_id) table_name 
from sys.default_constraints 
where is_system_named = 1

select name, object_name(object_id) table_name 
from sys.check_constraints 
where is_system_named = 1

select name, object_name(object_id) table_name 
from sys.key_constraints 
where is_system_named = 1
```

etc

Or you can look for the `__` in the names, but you would want to manually review those of course.

Comment: thanks so much! any idea of an automated solution to look for all the auto generated constraints and indexes?

Comment: See updated answer.